# MYSQL UNION WITH A LONG SCRIPT SHOWS ONLY FIRST SET OF SCRIPT

Tags: mysql

I have confusing situation about my very long script with `3724` lines. I have MYSQL version of 5.6 same with the server version but when i run the `VERY LONG SCRIPT WITH UNION` in my local machine it returns a result with:

```
5 rows only
```

and when i run it in another `Machine or in the Server Machine` it returns with:

```
12 rows
```

which is the correct result.

All this machine has the same `table and the same data` of the Database working.

When i investigate the `Script`, i found out that the problem is my `UNION` did not show the `second set of script`. I mean, only the `First Script shown.`.

My question is why union did not show all the result in my local machine?

Spend much time to search this situation in google but did not found a better solution for this.

I've been already done installing and uninstalling my `Mysql` but the problem is still the same.
Can't do to change another updated mysql version because it would be a conflict of my server version.

Any better ideas and advice is pretty much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you have a terminator before the union and it runs only the first part ? Hard to tell without being able to see the script. Make sure that you are connected to the right Server and DB and targeting the correct tables. Also try converting the Union to Union ALL for troubleshooting to see if it returns different.

Comment: actually i am using UNION ALL.. tried also UNION but it gave me the same result. Same Script tested in server and local but it returns different result. dont know why. anyway thanks for the comment

Comment: Either it's not the same user making the queries, or it's not the same data, or it's not the same queries, or it's not the same privileges (any fined grained access control?), or.. The trouble is that it'll be very difficult for someone without access to your systems to identify the reason.

Comment: Thanks @Scatte i am pretty sure that they are the same because when this error occur  i deeply do invetigate why is i happens. thats why i found out that the union is the problem. i am hoping that there is a set up for using union but unfortunately i failed.